# SE site-specific FAQs and an Area 51 FAQ

Tags: discussion, tags, area-51, meta-faq

#### Should significant SE sites have their own FAQ, and where should it be?

The SOFU FAQ works out well, IMHO, but it could use a lot more work.  I've done some, and hope to do more.  (Many of the problems are growing pains from before Meta existed, too.)

I think community FAQs are helpful to users and to contain a central, authoritative, updated reference point for regulars.  They can be much more detailed than the [offical FAQs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), and allow some discussion, clarification, and easy improvement from anyone in the community.

Perhaps obviously (but perhaps not?), every SE site shouldn't have a dedicated FAQ on Meta, but significant ones should.  With that in mind, Area 51 is significant enough, and different enough from other SE sites, to warrant its own.  Should "regular" SE sites host their own FAQ?  (That didn't work for SO, and there's a perceived need for a "meta" location for every site.  Is that meta site this Meta for all of them?)

#### The nascent [Area 51 community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52288/)

Will this succeed?  Is it in the right place?  How should it refer to the "main"/SOFU FAQ?  (Is the convention I started sufficient?)

How long should we wait before creating more FAQ questions? (How much time should AFO be given to settle down?)

Being limited to five tags total and requiring [area51], [faq]/[faq-proposed], and [support] only leaves room for **two** categorizing tags.  Is two enough?

Answer (score 1):

```
Should significant SE sites have their own FAQ [...]?
```

Yes they should (assuming you exclude SOFU): as you mentioned the SOFU FAQ works well and it is indeed very helpful to have *a central, authoritative, updated reference point for regulars*.

```
 [...] and where should it be?
```

Given that every SE site will have its own meta (see item 4 in the Area 51 FAQ section [Someone proposed a great site. How do I get involved?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq)), it seems obvious that this should be the place to live for a community FAQ for the respective site. Another benefit of this welcome 'meta decision' is that a community FAQ wouldn't be limited to significant sites only, as all follow the same pattern anyway, so you might as well start it for smaller sites early on.

(Besides, the Area 51 concept is implying a certain amount of significance a site must achieve for its continued existence anyway, doesn't it ;)

> That didn't work for SO, and there's a
> perceived need for a "meta" location
> for every site. Is that meta site this
> Meta for all of them?

See above, the decision that every community staged site will have its own meta has already been announced (see below), so this meta here will stay focused on the non community staged Stack Exchange sites as well as the Stack Exchange network in general.

---

**Update:**

<strike>I still haven't found the original announcement, but</strike> the recent blog article [Area 51: Asking the First Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/) from [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) ([Community Coordinator for Stack Exchange](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00005/)) does contain an official statement confirming this:

> As with each new Stack Exchange site,
> Web Apps received its own meta
> discussion forum to discuss issues
> such as the site’s design, what types
> of questions to ask, proper tagging,
> and picking a domain name